# json string to object with array

Tags: c#, json, json.net

```
var test = {'abc':76,'data':'[6435,3310,56.06875]'}
```

how do I convert above json string to an object say:

```
class item
{
    public string abc {Get;set;}
    public float[] data {get;set}
}
```

I tried 
`JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<item>(test);`
but get this error:

```
{"Error converting value \"[6435,3310]\" to type 'System.Single[]'. Path 'data', line 1, position 117."}
```

Comment: In what language/environment?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6620165/how-can-i-parse-json-with-c

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I parse JSON with C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6620165/how-can-i-parse-json-with-c)

Comment: OK, I find that it is because i have '[x,x,x]' instead of []

Comment: Hello @Zhongmin have a look at the solution provided by me and acknowledge if that works for you. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few problems with the json string (i am assuming you are using C#). First of the values of the `data` property are actually a string (given the quotes). Which is why you are getting the error.

What you could do is create a property to hold the string and then another property to parse the `float` values after parsed. This is done by using a few JSON.Net attributes of `JsonProperty` and `JsonIgnore`. These attributes tell the serializer what the property name is in the json string and which properties to ignore.

```
class Foo
{
    string dataString;
    float[] data = null;

    [JsonProperty("abc")]
    public string Abc { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("data")]
    public string DataString
    {
        get { return dataString; }
        set
        {
            data = null;
            dataString = value;
        }
    }

    [JsonIgnore]
    public float[] Data
    {
        get
        {
            if (data != null)
                return data;

            return data = dataString != null ? JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<float[]>(DataString) : null;
        }
        set
        {
            DataString = value == null ? null : JsonConvert.SerializeObject(value);
        }
    }
}
```

This looks like alot of code however uses backing fields to allow you to change both the `Data` field and the `DataString` field while maintaining a working serializer.

This is then simply called using

```
var i = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Foo>(test);
```

Answer (score 0):

This might do the trick for you

```
string jsn = @"{'abc':76,'data':'[6435,3310,56.06875]'}";
jsn = jsn.Replace("'[", "[");
jsn = jsn.Replace("]'", "]");
var ser = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ClsResult>(jsn);
```

I have used replace because `'data':'[6435,3310,56.06875]'` is making the array of data to string. So better we make it like `'data':[6435,3310,56.06875]` and then you class would look like

```
public class ClsResult
{
    [JsonProperty("abc")]
    public int abc { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("data")]
    public IList<double> data { get; set; }
}
```